# How to increase player Lifes count

Tags: c#, game-design, game-loop, unityscript

I am new in Unity Game Development. I am designing infinite game using C# scripting. 
There are many cubes in my game scene. if single cube is hit by player, He gets 100 points. 
if same color, two cubes are hit then gets 250 points.
if same color three cubes are hit, gets 500 points....

This kind functionality is used in my game. It increases my score. I want to increase player life after every 2000 points or above. for Example. first life increase 2000 or above, second 4000 or above, third 6000 or above...so on. I don't want to use if condition for every 2000 points because game is infinite.

I don't know how to solve this logic. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
// This is somewhere outside the update function
var lastPoints = 0;

// This is inside the update function
if(currentPoints - lastPoints > 2000) {
    increaseHealth();
    lastpoints = points;
}
```

This way you can infinitely increase the player hitpoints, until the points counter overflows.